# Sync and Un-sync in Collector

Tags: basemap, arcgis-collector

I'm new to Collector. I have a crew of people go out into the field to do offline collection at several sites. They downloaded a base map (activating sync) then noticed after the first day of data collection that the aerial needs to be updated to cover a broader area. I can't figure out how to download a new base map for offline use. Obviously we need internet connectivity, but even with connectivity there doesn't appear to be an easy way to get a new base. Anybody had this issue and found a work around or solution? I figure it should be something very simple. Other then making a totally new map and sharing it with the field staff, I can't figure out a simple work around.

Comment: Does your live map have the area required?  Should be able to just create a new offline map using Collector and specify a larger area of interest.  In our Collector apps the user creates his own offline map and specifies the area he wants.

Comment: I would assume this would be easy, but looks like the only way to do it is to create an entiurely new map, add editable layers, then share with field staff for use in Collector with snyc enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the sync/offline extent after its been downloaded. This is information stored when the map is downloaded to make sure the data downloaded and collected stays within your specified extent. If you need your field staff to collect data outside the original extent they would need to 
1) sync their changes, 
2) remove the map under the manage area in the app
3) redownload the map to cover a broader area. They can zoom out from where the extent is set and capture a broader area.

You could also just setup a new map entirely, leave the original one alone, have the field staff refresh their map gallery, download the new map with a new extent.